# How to manage socket connection on a iPhone web app that uses a node.js server?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, node.js, web

I'm new to node.js but I know it has a great socket API called socket.io. My question is: I want to build an iphone app that communicates with a database on a node.js server, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Do I build a standard index.html to which my app will attach to? How will the phone app create a socket? Will the socket be created when the app simply visits the website, e.g. www.example.com/index.html?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io has a client js library which you can use from a website hosted on any platform. It can be a simple static .html file, or a file returned from node.js (express view or similar).

As far as how to use it on the iPhone, it depends on how you plan on creating your app. I haven't used any native code which talks via socket.io, but a [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) application shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a native iPhone application, you can use the [Unitt Web Socket Client](http://code.google.com/p/unitt/). It provides a native, Objective-C web socket client that works with both ws and wss web socket connections.